# How to Add Diff Links to JS Buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

I created multiple buttons with Vanilla JS and want them to link to a different page. I'm thinking of mapping over the 'links' array but need a little refresher on how to target each individual button leading to the right page?

```js
const multipleButtons = () => {
  // let i = 0;
  let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var optionText = ["Fit Guide", "Care", "Materials"];
  var links = ['fitGuide.html', 'care.html', 'materials.html'];

  for (let i = 0; i < optionText.length; i++) {
    let button = document.createElement("button");
    //   button.innerHTML = 'Button '+i;
    button.innerHTML = optionText[i];
    body.appendChild(button);
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
      // alert(this.innerHTML);
    });
  }
}

multipleButtons();
```

Buttons work just fine, just gotta add the appropriate links. I know this can easily be done in HTML/CSS but I'm supposed to do this in plain JS.

Comment: What is your expected HTML output?

Comment: If you want links, use links (`<a href="">`) not buttons.

Comment: Are you looking for `button.addEventListener("click", function() {
       window.location.href = links[i];
    });`?

Comment: @Quentin apologies for not being clear. My purpose is to have each button link to a page, that is all. I'm looking to map over each element in the 'links' array, so first button(FitGuide) leads to /fitGuide.html, second button leads to second link, third to third link, so on so forth.

Comment: @j08691 YES THANK YOU LIFE SAVER. I was putting window.link.href the entire time smh. thanks!

Comment: @JessY. — Yes, that was clear, you should still use links for that and not buttons!

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use buttons and not an `a` tag, something like this:

```js
const multipleButtons = () => {
// let i = 0;
let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var optionText = ["Fit Guide", "Care", "Materials"];
var links = ['fitGuide.html', 'care.html', 'materials.html'];

for (let i=0; i < optionText.length; i++) {
  let button = document.createElement("button");
//   button.innerHTML = 'Button '+i;
     button.innerHTML = optionText[i];
     body.appendChild(button);
     button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
       window.location.href = "http://www.baseurl.com/path/to/page/"+links[i];
    });
  }
}



multipleButtons();
```

EDIT: changed to href instead of replace

Comment: `replace`?! Why mess with the back button like that?

Comment: `href` is a string property, not a function. *Uncaught TypeError: window.location.href is not a function*

Answer (score 0):

You can change your event listener to

```
button.addEventListener("click", function() { window.location.href = links[i]; });
```

Answer (score 0):

`for` loops have been proven to be faster, but [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loops are a bit more readable so I suggest you use those. It's also a good idea to use [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) for variables that won't change.

One last thing is that it's better to use `<a>` tags because that's what they were designed to do - like Quentin mentioned in the comments. You can style them to look like buttons if you want.

```js
const multipleButtons = () => {
  const optionText = ["Fit Guide", "Care", "Materials"];
  const links = ['fitGuide.html', 'care.html', 'materials.html'];

  optionText.forEach(function(text, index) {
    const anchor = document.createElement("a");
    anchor.innerText = text;
    anchor.href = links[index];
    document.body.appendChild(anchor);
    anchor.addEventListener("click", function() {
      alert(this.innerText);
      window.location.href = this.href;
    });
  });
}

multipleButtons();
```

```css
a {
  margin-right: .5em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks--yeah I changed them up to links instead afterwards!